Error: EACCES: permission denied when configuring https server on AWS Lightsail
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:596:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:464:35)
    at file:///home/bitnami/myproj/server/index.js:15:14
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key'
}

That's the error I get when I try to configure my express server that's deployed on AWS lightsail to use HTTPS. I added the https config like this:
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt'),
}
  
const server = https.createServer(options, app);

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 5000');
});

What's the proper way for me to grant permission to my express app to access the https files?

Can you change the permissions on the file? Use chmod 600 maybe?

@tbold I'll give that a try. I wasn't sure if I should be changing the file permissions for this

@tbold It worked but not for user role. Not sure if doing this is a security issue. thanks for the help tho
